# Assigning width of one control to other, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Let say we have controls c1 and c2

I want c2 to have width of c1 (c1 doesn't have fixed with, It should stretch automatically).

```
c2.Width = c1.Width;
c2.Width = c1.Width.Value;
```

These doesn't work.

Can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you running that code?  When you assign to the width, it will assign the value at the time that you run the code.  This is an example of a value assignment.  If you want C2 to resize whenever c1 resizes, you need to assign it every time C1 changes.  You can do this in the control's [resize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resize.aspx) event.

Answer (score 1):

you can folllow this way

c2.Size = New Size(c1.width, c2.height)

Please also make sure that Control.AutoSize property has been set to false before setting new Size. If “true”, it will not resize itself.

Furthermore, some controls like TextBox has not AutoSize property, thus cannot be resized as you wish. Only width of TextBox can be reset successfully.

For more information of specific control’s AutoSize property, please refer to its MSDN document.

Thanks.